# Print Screen key going to black and white

Tags: windows-xp, colors, screen-capture

Running Windows XP I am finding that printScreen button only captures a black and white image of the full screen but color for just one window (Alt-PrintScreen).

Is there a limit to how much memory can be used for the image that I am hitting here?  My screen is huge 2560x1600 pixels, so maybe it drops depth to 1 bit to save memory.

If true, is there a way around this limitation?

Comment: Maybe paste it into a different imaging program? Irfanview is great at handling screenshots and all types of images. If it's still broken, then you know it's not your image viewer/editor.

Comment: I'm using Adobe Photoshop, but pasting into Microsoft Paint has the same issue.

Comment: But only after Photoshop has been launched once since booting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it was some corruption introduced by some combination of Adobe Photoshop CS4 and the nVidia graphics drivers.

Comment: Rebooting and not launching Photoshop after boot and all works fine, once Photoshop is launched, the weirdness starts.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue on my Windows 7 machine. For me, it was due to a remote desktop session I had open to an old windows server. The remote desktop window was minimised, but it was still interfering with screen shots taken on my desktop.